# Sharing parent/child groups between scenes

Tags: scene, asset-browser

I have a model vehicle with 4 wheels parented to a body. The wheels are set up to rotate when the body moves.

However, I'd like to use this vehicle (body + wheels) in other scenes.
Is there a way to 'share' this parent/child group?

I've tried making it into a collection - but the wheels no longer rotate.
I've tried selecting both, pressing ctrl+L and linking to another scene - but everything is shared including location.

What I'm aiming to achieve is a series of scenes where the vehicle rolls in, various bits are added. At the end of the scene, the vehicle with it's extra parts is then used by the next scene etc etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work in this way - make an armature and parent body and wheels to different bones. Then pack car and armature into collection. Then link this collection and use Object  - Relations - make library override. Now you will be able to enter pose mode and rotate wheels and move the car

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made a very simple armature with 2 bones - one main bone, and a 2nd one that transforms rotation based on the main bones location, then attached the wheel to this bone - and it works nicely.